# Simply-connected covers of group schemes

Tags: reference-request, group-schemes

Let $\mathbf G$ be a semisimple group scheme over a base $S$. I believe that one can always find a fiberwise simply-connected group scheme $\mathbf G^{sc}$ and a central isogeny $\mathbf G^{sc}\to\mathbf G$, moreover, these data is unique up to a unique isomorphism (one might need to assume that $S$ is locally Noetherian and reduced). I wonder if this is a known statement and if it there is a reference? I was not able to find this statement in SGA3.

Comment: Are you assuming some hypothesis on the characteristic?  In characteristic $p$ dividing $n$, for instance, the central isogeny from $\textbf{SL}_n$ to $\textbf{PGL}_n$ is not etale.  I have not checked it, but possibly that causes problems over imperfect fields of characteristic $p$.

Comment: Hi Jason, I am certainly not assuming any hypothesis on the characteristic, so the central isogeny is not expected to be etale. Also, when I say "simply-connected" I mean "as an algebraic group". That is, not a target of a central isogeny with a connected source.

Comment: Maybe it is fine: the bad examples I know of nonreduced finite group schemes that are only defined after purely inseparable extension are unipotent group schemes.  On the other hand, the center of a semisimple group scheme is always of multiplicative type.